# How to prepare SQL query dynamically (column names too) avoiding SQL injection

Tags: php, html, mysqli, sql-injection, bindparam

I recently learned about SQL Injection and the PHP recommendation to avoid it, using `prepare()` and `bind_param()`. 
Now, I want to prepare SQL queries dynamically, adding both column names and values.

I usted to do it like this, having the `name` field of the HTML input with the same name as the MySQL database column.

```
    <input type="text" name="firstname" >
    <input type="text" name="lastname" >
```

And the, create the SQL query dynamically using mysqli.

```
    // Extract values from POST
    $parameters = $_POST;
    // Organize the values in two strings
    foreach ($parameters as $id => $value) {
        $fields = $fields . "`" . $id . "`,";
        $values = $values . "'" . $value . "',"; 

        /*e.g.
            $fields = `firstname`,`lastname`
            $values = 'John','Wick'
        */
    }

    // Write into the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `user` ($fields) VALUES ($values)";

    /*e.g.
        INSERT INTO `user` (`firstname`,`lastname`) VALUES ('John','Wick')
    */
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do this using `prepare()` and `bind_param()` to avoid SQL injection, may be adding adding some `data-type="s"` to the HTML input tag or if there is a better, more best-practices, way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use bound parameters only for an element that would be a constant value — a quoted string, a quoted datetime, or a numeric literal.

You can't use a parameter placeholder for anything else in SQL, like column names, table names, lists of values, SQL keywords or expressions, or other syntax.

If you need to make column names dynamic, the only option is to validate them against a list of known columns.

```
$columns_in_user_table = [
  'userid'=>null,
  'username'=>'',
  'firstname'=>'',
  'lastname'=>''
];
// Extract values from POST, but only those that match known columns
$parameters = array_intersect_key($_POST, $columns_in_user_table);
// Make sure no columns are missing; assign default values as needed
$parameters = array_merge($columns_in_user_table, $parameters);
```

If you use PDO instead of mysqli, you can skip the binding. Just use named parameters, and pass your associative array of column-value pairs directly to `execute()`:

```
$columns = [];
$placeholders = [];
foreach ($parameters as $col => $value) {
    $columns[] = "`$col`";
    $placeholders[] = ":$col";
}
$column_list = implode($columns, ',');
$placeholder_list = implode($placeholders, ',');

// Write into the database
$sql = "INSERT INTO `user` ($column_list) VALUES ($placeholder_list)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($parameters);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I need. I'll switch to PDO. I have a doubt: 
As we are using name parameters with the `:$col` line, isn't it required that the `$parameters` array has the form `array(':firstname' => 'John',':lastname' => 'Wick')`, with the colon before the  _col_ name?

Comment: The colon in bound parameter keys was required many years ago, but I think someone realized there was no reason for it, and it made it more work to convert a $_POST array directly into the params needed. I forget which version of PHP changed it, but as long as you're not using an end-of-life version of PHP, you're well past the need to put colons in your binding names. They are required only in the SQL query.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed you included the mysqli tag on your question, so assuming your database is MySQL and you are using the native MySQL functions, then you can do something like this:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);

$code = 'DEU';
$language = 'Bavarian';
$official = "F";
$percent = 11.2;

/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

And yes, I ripped that straight out of the [PHP manual page on mysqli_stmt_bind_param.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer!
But, I would like to create the SQL statement adding the column names, as `CountryLanguage`, the required amount of `?` symbols, and the data type string, like the `'sssd'` using a loop or a function instead of creating the prepared query in a static way as in your example.